# Yii2: Should I store related models in separate variable first?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm wondering about how to best refer to attributes in [Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/)'s related [ActiveRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord) models. Is it fine to do this:

```php
$order->customer->address;
$order->customer->city;
$order->customer->zip;
$order->customer->country;
```

Or will that result in more database queries or more work for PHP so that I should rather do this?

```
$customer = $order->customer;
$customer->address;
$customer->city;
$customer->zip;
$customer->country;
```

Comment: It doesnt matter really, most probably such things are optoimized when compiling...The main thing is to manage which relations should be lazy and which should be get immidiately with main model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this official article](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/834/relational-query-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-in-yii-2-0), the first variant will not result into more DB queries, but will call a getter for `customer` more times. If you have to write a high loaded service, than you have to write in the second way to reduce the getter calls. Otherwise it's just your choice.

Comment: So the question becomes how many resources it takes to do those `getter` calls (because I assume it recreates the model object every time) and at which point you have a "high loaded service"...

Comment: @TheStoryCoder your assumption is wrong. The model object is not recreated every time the getter is called. You can see how the getter is implemented [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L285)

Comment: Ahh, so it actually just reuses the created instance of the class. Then my guess is that any performance hit would be practically nonexistent...

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Treat this mostly as micro-optimization. It may matter on tight loops, but in most cases it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is ok, related model is loaded only once.

When you access the `$customer` property the ActiveRecord first checks if the related model is already loaded in private property `$_related`. If it's already there then it's returned without loading.

If they are not loaded yet the ActiveRecord loads them and stores them in `$_related`.

This is called `lazy loading`.

You can also force `eager loading` by using something like `$query->with('customer')` while building query that loads the order. Eager loading means that the customer model will be loaded right when order model is loaded.